# Handling user data in a more streamlined and efficient way

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm retooling the engine for a simulation I'm programming. The problem is that there's a massive amount of data passed between many objects, that is ultimately serialized.

The way I had it programmed before I decided to go ahead and rewrite the whole thing was with class variables (i.e. Clock.time, Clock.format, etc.). I realize this is "bad" programming, and instead I am keeping a dictionary of dictionaries, which makes for easy serialization. The problem I have is it is resulting in code that looks like this mess:

```
import save_data
def example_of_an_object(branch, data, input):
    if not data['python']['foo']: return branch, data, "False."
    else:
        if not branch['leaf']:
            branch.update({'leaf' : '1'})
            print("{} is on leaf {}".format(data['user']['name'], branch['leaf']))
        elif branch['leaf'] == "1":
            if data['python']['foo'] == "Hello":
                data.update('python':{'foo': "bye"})
                save_data.shelving(data['python'])
                print("Good Bye")
        else: pass
        return branch, data, input
```

Is there a better way to represent this data? Note that there are sometimes several child dictionaries used in one object, sometimes just one, so I'm trying to keep everything as uniform as possible (as far as attributes go).

Comment: By the way, `branch['leaf'] == False` should be replaced with `not branch['leaf']`(according to PEP8). And `else: pass` line is unnecessary.

Comment: And do not rebind built-in name if you didn't intend it. `object` is built-in name. You can rename it `object_` by PEP8 guide. But I recommend to name function starting with verb.

Comment: You learn something new every day. As far as else: pass, I know the program would function without it, but I prefer to have it. (Also, this is a simplified version of code I have. It's not an actual snippet, because I thought it might detract in readability).

Answer (score 1):

It is unnecessary to be pythonic:

```
Select = { # use the branch['leaf'] value to get the statement and execute it.
    False:'''Your statement''',
    "1":'''another statement'''
}

def object(branch, data, input):
    if Select.get(branch['leaf']):
        exec(Select[branch["leaf"]])
    return branch, data, ("False." if not data['python']['foo'] else input)
```

An easy example:

```
Select = {
    False:'''

if True:
    print("Yes")

''',
}

exec(Select[False])
```

Comment: Huh, I never would have thought to approach that code from this angle. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @downwithocp `exec()` maybe will cause some serious problem.Limit or do some string-processings for user's input.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I have to do some thinking now about how to use this information, but fortunately user inputs are filtered through a processor. I will do my reading on exec.